# ngChange not getting called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have ngChange on directive which is not getting fired.

```
<cs-number-field options="fields.age" ng-model="age" ng-change="update()"></cs-number-field>
```

the ng-change i have received in directive scope using '&'

```
scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=', ngChange: '&' },
```

also the way i have populated it in template is:

```
html += '<input type="number" name="myfield" placeholder="{{options.placeholder}}" ng-required="options.required" ' +
    ' ng-pattern="{{options.pattern}}" ng-minlength="{{options.minlength}}" max="{{options.max}}" step="any" ' +
    ' ng-maxlength="{{options.maxlength}}" ng-readonly="options.readonly" min="{{options.min}}" ' +
    ' autofocus="options.autofocus" ng-change="scope.ngChange" data-ng-model="ngModel"/>';
```

but the ngChange is not getting fired.
Note: i have update function defined on controller: [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HpO5sVPPePKMpv8MN9t?p=preview)

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call it like this

```
scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=', ngChange: '=' },
```